# Querystring - How to send hidden parameters and cleaning the url

Tags: vb.net, query-string

In one of my current websites I use querystring parameters in order to send items from one page to another and grab info from DB's.

Currently my URL looks like this http://www.mysite.com/mt?=AA112233

I'd like to be able to replace this code and generate the url to be like http://www.mysite.com/some-form-of-logical-url but with the requesting page able to get the querystring parameter of AA112233.

I'm currently struggling to find the best method to do this - any help would be appreciated on best practice for this change.

Thanks!